# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' Error on Airflow Bash Operator

Tags: debian, airflow

My airflow bash operator suddenly getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

It was worked perfectly for the last 2 months but stop working from yesterday. I didn't change anything on the server or didn't update my server.

Answer (score 1):

BashOperator simply runs bash command on your machine. So check if your machine has `pandas` installed on it. If not, do `pip install pandas`