# BashOperator not found on Airflow install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, airflow

I'm not sure how to approach this issue -- other posts to do with `ModuleNotFoundError` are solved by reinstalling the relevant package, however it's clear that this is not the issue because the example bash operator DAG runs. So is my issue to do with how Airflow was installed? At this point I'm looking at reinstalling Airflow via the [puckel Docker container](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

```
[2020-12-23 01:02:24,705] {dagbag.py:259} ERROR - Failed to import: /home/pi/airflow/dags/dag_clist.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/airflow/dags/dag_clist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.bash'
```

Other SO posts to do with the BashOperator:

- [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953410/getting-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-error-on-airflow-bash-oper)
- [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024889/airflow-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyspark)

Comment: Have you investigated whether this feature was implemented in a particular version? Which version do you have?

Comment: @tripleee I used the most recent stable release on the [airflow github project](https://github.com/apache/airflow) `pip install apache-airflow==1.10.14 \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.14/constraints-3.7.txt"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using Airflow 1.10.14 The import should be

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
```

In Airflow >= 2.0.0 it's:

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
```